# Convert Strings To Date In VBA In A for Each Loop

Tags: string, excel, vba, date

I Have a column with dates as string like 15/06/2015, but the type is string, and at the same column I have real dates types, my problem is that when run the code the erro "no matches variables" here is my code.

```
Sub arrumadata3()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Plan1").Activate

    For Each MyCell In Range("F:F")

        MyCell.Value = CDate("MyCell.Value")


Next MyCell


End Sub
```

I dont even try is the cell value is date, i'm just trying to converte each cell, even if that is empty.

PS. Sorry about some english mistakes, english is not my firt language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

MyCell.Value =  Format(MyCell.Value, "mmmm dd, yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

You were very close:

```
Sub arrumadata3()
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets("Plan1").Activate
        For Each MyCell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("F:F"))
            MyCell.Value = CDate(MyCell.Value)
        Next MyCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution still go to the error "Execution time error 13: no matches types" in that line MyCell.Value = CDate(MyCell.Value)

Comment: @AlexandreGentil  Update your post with a picture of your data and we will resolve the issue.